# Unable to make a table with nested clickable rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edited-

I am trying to make a table with nested rows. If I click on the parent row it should expand/collapse to show the child row.

Here is the code that I have been trying.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GUNCLFIZ8JA8

But this is not working. I need to click on the parent to open child. And if I click on Child row it should open child2 row.

Here is the wireframe how it should look.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. The given markup is not valid, also this question looks pretty unrelated to JS or Sass to me

Comment: @NicoHaase I have made the edits. I am new to this so not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

*Updated example*

I have added padding for child rows. A table within a table is not neccessary for that.

Be aware this is just an example HTML & CSS. I don't have time to code the whole thing for you.
This might not be easier to work with than tables within tables but probably easier to render.

```css
table { margin: 10px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #0b0; background-color: #080; color: #eee; }
th { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #b0b; background-color: #808; }
td { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #00b; background-color: #008; }

tr.tr-child.depth-1 td { padding-left: 20px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-2 td { padding-left: 40px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-3 td { padding-left: 60px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-4 td { padding-left: 80px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-5 td { padding-left: 100px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-6 td { padding-left: 120px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-7 td { padding-left: 140px; }
tr.tr-child.depth-8 td { padding-left: 160px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-parent">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-parent tr-child depth-1">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-child depth-2">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-parent">
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-parent tr-child depth-1">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-child depth-2">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the scenario

Comment: Okay good. I have updated an example solution. It's a simple aproach but sometimes those are the better ones.